# How do I insert the values of the radio-buttons in my database, and what table layout should I use?

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I have a questionlist and I can post the answers but now I don't know how to put them in the database. I also don't know what kind of table-Layout I should use.

I tried some things but they would work because you have multiple answers so it can't insert all at once. I was using one "answers" colomn in my table because I can't make 1000 "answers" colomns because not every questionlist has as much questions as a other one.

```
<form action="Antwoord.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="Naam" placeholder="Uw naam:">
<?php
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM  questionlist_choice WHERE Qid='1'";
   $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $i = 0;
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$vraag = $row['Vraag'];
$vraagA = $row['Vraag_keuzeA'];
$vraagB = $row['Vraag_keuzeB'];
$vraagC = $row['Vraag_keuzeC'];
$vraagD = $row['Vraag_keuzeD'];
$vraagE = $row['Vraag_keuzeE'];
$vraagF = $row['Vraag_keuzeF'];
echo "<div>";
    echo "<br><p>$vraag</p>";
    echo "<input type='radio' name='q[$i]' value='$vraagA'> $vraagA<br>";
    echo "<input type='radio' name='q[$i]' value='$vraagB'> $vraagB<br>";
    echo "<input type='radio' name='q[$i]' value='$vraagC'> $vraagC<br>";
    echo "<input type='radio' name='q[$i]' value='$vraagD'> $vraagD<br>";
    echo "<input type='radio' name='q[$i]' value='$vraagE'> $vraagE<br>";
    echo "<input type='radio' name='q[$i]' value='$vraagF'> $vraagF<br>";

echo "</div>";
$i++;

?>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create 3 different tables:

USERS, QUESTIONS, and ANSWERS

Structure:

```
 users:
     - id 
     - name
     - other data you store ...
 surveys:
     - id
     - name or whatever data you store about survey
 questions
     - id
     - survey_id
     - text (actual question)
     - ...
 answers
     - id
     - user_id
     - question_id
     - answer
```

If you want to insert all answers in one column (which I don't recommend)
you can [serialize](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) the answers

You will also have to use different db structure

```
answers:
    - id
    - user_id
    - survey_id
    - answers
```

Change you $i to 1 so your questions ids start with 1;

```
  $i = 1;
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
       // also change the name to just $i
       echo "<input type='radio' name='.$i.' value='$vraagA'> $vraagA<br>";
```

Posting to db:

```
// put all checkbox values in a single array
$answers = [];
for($i = 1; $i<= $numberOfAnswers; $i++) {
    $answers[$i] = $_POST[$i];
}
$answers = serialize($answers);

// do the insert query
```

Comment: I also don't like the everything in one but it is for multiple survey's and I don't know how much questions/ answers there are for all of them so the best thing to do atm is all in one.

Comment: @Niels040 But with the structure I've gave you initially, you dont need to know how many questions/answers there are, thats the beauty of pivot tables.

Comment: I didnt realize that you have multiple surveys, I've edited my answer again

Comment: am I ment to change $numberOfanswers to something else bc its Undefined.

Comment: Yes, you should put the number of answers/questions for survey there, you can either hardcode it based on survey type, count the number of questions you have for that survey in db, etc.

Comment: Ill hardcode it for now but how do you count them? Sorry if i ask to much this is my second year in my study.

Comment: If you have only answers in your  $_POST variable, you can use count($_POST), if you have some other values other than answers you can subtract them from post count. But probalby the best way would to select count of all questions for that survey from a database and put it there,

Comment: Is there maybe a way we could communicate easier. So I could send you the file because that might be faster. ( If you want, you don't have to )

Comment: @Niels040 Sorry but I cant accept files from strangers online, especially on my work computer, and I should really get back to work :). Also Stack Overflow is not code writing service, I think that you have enough info now to figure out the details yourself. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

In `Antwoord.php` you need logic like this.

```
 <?php
    if (isset($_POST['q1'])){
        $q1 = $_POST['q1'];
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO vraag (q1) VALUES ('$q1')");
    }
  ?>
```

Comment: Thats only for 1 and i need all of them.

Comment: Wrap the whole thing in a loop